# How to get a specific value from HttpContext.Current.Session["PaTSUA"] whch contains a list of values?

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I want to select a particular value from a session variable. How can I get that value from this session

```
var tz = HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"];
```

this is the code I am using. When I execute this in the immediate window it shows the result like this

```
{PS.UserInterface.Models.UA}
ApplicationID: {de151484-f822-4692-a36b-e7e1fc1066fe}
CompanyID: {fef3fb8e-365f-4cc4-8976-ff9e5ed1516c}
DBConnectionString: "Data Source=WIN-ISPHTIHPJFI\\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=PSDefault;User ID=dba;Password=dba@2018"
DefaultModuleID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
IsMainContractor: true
LicenseID: {ac258d7d-25dc-44f9-b798-2d4657d68c95}
LicenseType: "MultiUser"
LoginName: "suvaneeth"
LoginTime: "11-Apr-2019 18:39:34"
RolesCSV: "SAAdmin"
ThemeCode: "Liquid"
TimeZone: "Dateline Standard Time"
UserID: {fc938df0-8a4e-4c85-b93c-be51373c559f}
UserName: "Suvaneeth S"
UserProfileID: {fc938df0-8a4e-4c85-b93c-be51373c559f}
UserWeekStartDay: "1"
licenseModuleCSV: "830683B5-6D12-4AF9-AF76-7013A930AA0D,F774DF88-C2D6-4527-8A0E-493E1E1D3120"
```

But I don't get any idea of how can I get TimeZone from this result

Comment: What is that object type name?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand ?

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN i want to select TimeZone from this session

Comment: Something like `(HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"] as PS.UserInterface.Models.UA).TimeZone`?

Comment: you could use cast it to dynamic and just get a property value

Comment: @Gene ya i want that TimeZone value

Comment: could you share assigning code like HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"]= yourobject;

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN ya i already write it with the question

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN i am assigning it to a variable tz

Comment: lookat my example again i said HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"]= yourobject;

Comment: or you can do that as vhr comment

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN ok let me try with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to do it like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var test = new test { abc = "asdasdasd" };
        var xx = (dynamic)test;
        Console.WriteLine(xx.abc);
    }

    class test
    {
        public string abc { get; set; }
    }
```

so for you:

```
var tz = HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"];
var xx = (dynamic)tz;
var zone = tz.TimeZone;
```

Comment: im using this session in DataAccessLayer of my project . So creating a property there is practical?

Comment: @dhanilDinesan you can store it if you're using it more often

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to UA class like;

```
var tz = (PS.UserInterface.Models.UA)HttpContext.Current.Session["PaUA"];
var timezoneValue= tz.TimeZone;
```

Comment: But in DataAccessLayer i cannot access UserInterface right?

Comment: Pass session value as a parameter into method, don't use session in DataAccesLayer @DhanilDinesan

Comment: Is there any security issue or something like that if i used it in DataAccessLayer

Comment: There is no security issue. But don't keep personel informations in session. For instance If you want to keep password in session, you should keep crypted version password, when you want to use it decrypt it on backend.